# Ensure a Java Path is relative and 'downward'

Tags: java, filesystems

Given a Java Path object, how can I safely ensure that, if I call root.resolve(path), that it will refer to something below root?

For example, I want to be able to reject something like '../someotherdir' while accepting 'somesubdir/another/afile'.

I'd be happy to reject or accept 'somesubdir/../afile' depending on what proved most convenient.

I want to perform this check before I actually know what root will be, so the obvious solution of checking something like `root.resolve(path).toRealPath().startsWith(root))` doesn't really suit, and checking for my own list of path elements to reject seems dangerous because I'm likely to overlook something.

I am aware that:

- Different file systems may interpret things differently, so I'm willing to restrict this to FileSystem.getDefault().
- Symlinks contained below wherever the eventual root is may result in the path referring out. I'm willing to live with that or externally confirm there are no such symlinks below root.

Comment: How about extracting the first element of `path.normalize()` and resolving it against a dummy relative `Path` consisting of a single, non-empty element?  If the result `startsWith()` the dummy `Path` then you should be ok.  Do note that this will always yield `false` if `path` is absolute.  That seems sensible to me, but it might be surprising under certain circumstances.